# Bootstrap data attribute collapse prevent conflicting animations

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I've used some clever selectors to make two radio buttons either hide or show a div using Bootstrap's `data-toggle="collapse"` tool.

If I click "Show", the div appears, and if I click "Hide", it collapses.

But if, while the div is visible, I click "Hide" then "Show" again very quickly, "Show" is checked, but the div is not visible.

I'm very happy with using `data-*` attributes instead of custom Javascript... is there a way to prevent these "conflicting animations", if that is what they are?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<input id="rbone" 
    type="radio" 
    name="group" 
    data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#thing:not(.show)" />
<label for="rbone">Show</label><br />
<input id="rbtwo" 
    type="radio" 
    name="group" 
    data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#thing.show" />
<label for="rbtwo">Hide</label>

<div id="thing" class="collapse">Nothing to see here.</div>
```

Comment: Do you try to bring your scripts to the bottom of HTML file?

Comment: Yep, the scripts are at the bottom. How might that make a difference?

Comment: I think without javascript preventdefault, you can't

Comment: Did my answer help you? You said javascript trickery was welcome.

Comment: @Dream_Cap your answer may be the way to go... but slightly better for my application would be a JS "fix" for the html-coded toggle. That way the behavior is obvious without looking at the JS (this form may be maintained by multiple people). Does that make sense?

Comment: I have updated the answer with an option 2 for the jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jquery way of doing it:

```
//On click of show, fade in 
$( ".show" ).click(function() {
  $('#thing').fadeIn();
});

//On click of hide, fade out
$( ".hide" ).click(function() {
  $('#thing').fadeOut();
});
```

**option 2**

```
$( ":radio" ).click(function() {
    //if radio button has the class show, fade In
    if ($(this).hasClass('show')){
    $('#thing').fadeIn();
      //if radio button has the class hide, fade out
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('hide')) { 
    $('#thing').fadeOut();
  }

});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<input id="rbone" type="radio" name="group" class="show" />

<label for="rbone">Show</label>
<br />
<input id="rbtwo" type="radio" name="group" class='hide'/>
<label for="rbtwo">Hide</label>

<div id="thing">
  <p>
    Nothing to see here
  </p>.</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swtdwce3/5/). You can add this to a file like "app.js", then include it in your html file like

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution by using the pure CSS. Here If the show radio button is selected by using the CSS selector `~` I applied the style for sibling content.

**CSS**

```
   #rbone:checked ~ #thing {
         display: block !important;
    }
```

**DEMO**

```css
/* Updated CSS  */

#rbone:checked ~ #thing {
display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<input id="rbone" 
    type="radio" 
    name="group" 
    data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#thing:not(.show)" />
<label for="rbone">Show</label><br />
<input id="rbtwo" 
    type="radio" 
    name="group" 
    data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#thing.show" />
<label for="rbtwo">Hide</label>

<div id="thing" class="collapse">Nothing to see here.</div>
```

Comment: Very nice! Can this be expanded to make sure #thing is hidden when you click Hide and then quickly > Show > Hide?

Comment: Here the show/hide will work fine except the animation because we cannot animate the "height: 0px to auto;", My solution lightweight, and it works well in any case except animation.

Comment: And if you need animation you want to set "max-height" value.

Answer (score 0):

Add **show** class into **thing** id with show input **checked** attribute. without adding extra css or js code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<input id="rbone" 
    type="radio" 
    name="group" 
    data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#thing:not(.show)" checked />
<label for="rbone">Show</label><br />
<input id="rbtwo" 
    type="radio" 
    name="group" 
    data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#thing.show" />
<label for="rbtwo">Hide</label>

<div id="thing" class="collapse show">Nothing to see here.</div>
```